# What is consuming power with PIC18?

Tags: embedded, sleep, microcontroller, pic

I have a very simple code that print out something to the terminal then goes directly to sleep.

For some reason the device is consuming more current during sleep mode. It is drawing 0.24 mA but I know it should be less than that. Without sleep it is consuming 4.32 mA. I've ran the most basic software I can and must be missing something.

Please what are some of the factors that effect power consumption? I really need to lower power consumption but I don't know what's causing it be that high. Here is the [Datasheet](http://seniordesign.ee.nd.edu/2008/Design%20Teams/Awesome-o/datasheets/39778b.pdf) for your own convenience.

```
/*  
     File: main.c
     Date: 2011-SEP-4
     Target: PIC18F87J11
     IDE: MPLAB 8.76
     Compiler: C18 3.40

 */  
 #include <p18cxxx.h>
 #include <usart.h>

     #pragma config FOSC = HSPLL, WDTEN = OFF, WDTPS = 4096, XINST = OFF 

 #define FOSC (4000000UL)
 #define FCYC (FOSC/4UL)

 #define BAUD 9600UL
 #define SPBRG_INIT (FOSC/(16UL*BAUD) - 1)

 void main(void)
 {   
     /* set FOSC clock to 4MHZ */
     OSCCON = 0x70;

     /* turn off 4x PLL */
     OSCTUNE = 0x00;

     /* make all ADC inputs digital I/O */
     ANCON0 = 0xFF;
     ANCON1 = 0xFF;


     /* test the simulator UART interface */
     Open1USART(USART_TX_INT_OFF & USART_RX_INT_OFF & USART_ASYNCH_MODE & USART_EIGHT_BIT & USART_CONT_RX & USART_BRGH_HIGH, SPBRG_INIT);
     putrs1USART("PIC MICROCONTROLLERS\r\n");
     Close1USART();

     /* sleep forever */
     Sleep();

 }
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update 1:** I noticed adding the following code decreased it to 0.04 mA

```
TRISE = 0;
PORTE = 0x0C;
```

And If I was to change `PORTE` to the following, it increased to 0.16 mA.

```
PORTE = 0x00;
```

But I don't really understand what all of that means ... or how the power consumption went down. I have to be missing something in the code but I don't know what it is.

**Update 2:** This code gives me unstable current consumption. Sometimes 2.7 mA other times 0.01 mA. I suspect the problem with `WDTCONbits.REGSLP = 1;`

[Download Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3ulsfnc5qh3sei/main.c)

Comment: Common things to look for (not PIC specific) include oscillator still running at high frequency, unneeded peripherals powered up, and signals driven against pullup / pulldown resistors.  Also, floating inputs may consume substantially more power than those which are completely high or low.  Finally note that your measuring scheme can be distorted by current leaking in or out through the data pins of interfaces for a programmer, serial data connection, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Current consumption nicely went down from 0.24 mA to 0.04 mA when OP change settings on port outputs.

This is expected in typical designs, the outputs control various circuitry.  Example: An output, by driving **high**, may turn on an LED(1), taking an additional 0.20 mA.  In another design, an output, by driving **low**, may turn on an LED. In a 3rd design, **not driving** may turn on an LED.

OP needs to consult the schematic or designer to determine what settings result in low power.  Further, certain combinations may/may not be allowed during low power mode.

Lastly, the *sequence* of lowering power, disabling, etc. on the various design elements may be important.  The sequence to to shut things down is usually reversed in bringing them back on-line.

@Chris Stratton has good ideas in the posted comment.

---

(1) A *low* powered LED.

Comment: In terms of design, high turns on an output. I have disabled all peripherals, made all pins outputs, and assigned them low but that did not help. I still don't know what's consuming more current, I am lost!

Comment: Investigation idea: I'm not so confident that your peripherals are all disabled or can be.  Try disabling all peripherals  - don't sleep, just loop - and notice the current consumption.  Then try disabling all peripherals and then turn 4X PLL off.  Your new current should be 1/4.  If not, you have some peripheral(s) that is not a function of your clock speed.  That difference should remain even is you sleep (bring clock to 0).

Comment: UART idea:  Your post does not indicate that you put the serial I/F into low power mode (if possible) _after_ you sent the test message.  Is _that_ I/F an RS-232 one with +V & -V levels?  You need to disable that I/F's drivers to get it into a low power mode. Simple not sending data is not low power, but may be the best you can get.

Comment: I disabled all the peripherals and kept the device on run mode, the current consumption was .14 mA. Then I disabled all the peripherals and put the device to sleep, the current consumption was .04 mA. About the UART, I am not using it anymore, I removed it from the code.

Comment: @Ammar Removing code does not remove the Serial Interface from the circuit - it still consumes power if you uses it or not.  Do you have the ability to disable the serial transmitter??.  That could be the remaining 0.04 mA usage.

Comment: I have managed to lower the current consumption down to 0.01 mA or 3.2 uA in sleep mode. However, I am noticing inconsistency in the current consumption.  Sometimes when I turn on the PIC, the current consumption is 2.70 mA and other times it is 0.01 mA. I don't know what's causing it to act this way, do you have any clue?

Comment: @Ammar  I'm tapped out.  I suspect the peripherals.  Need to know more details than this forum allows.

Comment: @Ammar Will not be able to deeply review for a couple days.

Comment: No problem, whenever you get a chance.